# Creating a popup in Blazor using C# method

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have a simple page `index.razor` with a button:

```
<a class="btn btn-login" @onclick="RedirectPage" >Log in</a>

<div
    @bind-Visible="@InvalidLogin"
    BodyText="Error">
</div>

@code{
    InvalidLogin {get; set;} = false;
}
```

Where the function `RedirectPage` checks if values are valid. If they are not, I want a popup giving information:

```
private void RedirectPage
{
    this.InvalidLogin = true;
}
```

This function is in the `index.razor.cs` and has been added with `@using` in the correct namespace.

How can I create it so that a popup shows up whenever the button is clicked?

Comment: When you say "popup" are you talking about a modal dialog?  If so, which CSS framework are you using?  If so, check out this answer and my answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882886/is-it-possible-to-load-dynamically-existing-page-in-a-bootstrap-modal-body/71888010#71888010

Comment: Understand that on the client side a pop-up is just a div or other element that is styled to appear in front of other elements. One very simple way of achieving this  is to put a div in your Layout page.  You can pass your layout page to all its children using the “this” keyword, And then use a method on the layout page to change the CSS class of the pop-up element.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a simple popup (or modal dialog) component. Below, I wrote a sample popup razor component using Bootstrap 5 toast component.

`Popup.razor` file

```cs
@{
    var showClass = IsVisible ? "d-block" : "d-none";
}

<div class="toast-container p-3 @showClass" data-bs-autohide="true" data-bs-delay="5000">
    <div class="toast show" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <strong class="me-auto">@HeaderText</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" @onclick="Close"></button>
        </div>

        <div class="toast-body">
            @BodyText
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> IsVisibleChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? HeaderText { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? BodyText { get; set; }

    public void Show(string bodyText, string headerText = "")
    {
        HeaderText = headerText;
        BodyText = bodyText;
        IsVisible = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void Close()
    {
        HeaderText = string.Empty;
        BodyText = string.Empty;
        IsVisible = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Using the `Popup` razor component in your code:

```cs
<a class="btn btn-login" @onclick="RedirectPage" >Log in</a>

<Popup @ref="popupRef" />

@code{
    private Popup popupRef;
    
    private void RedirectPage()
    {
        // Shows the popup at the center of the screen
        popupRef.Show("Popup body text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, with some changes I got this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your simple way, how to close it when user `clicks` outside of popup?

Answer (score 6):

How to create a dialog without a dependency on a third party library.

I had to use a minimal amount of js as the new HTML5 `<dialog...` element can only be opened in dialog mode with it `.showModal()` not by manipulating attributes.

`wwwroot/scripts/dialogJsInterop.js`

```
export function showDialog(element, parm) {
    return element.showModal();
}

export function closeDialog(element, parm) {
    return element.close();
}
```

`Dialog.razor`

```
<CascadingValue Value=@this IsFixed=true >
    <dialog @ref="@dialogElement" @attributes=@CapturedAttributes>
    @if(visible)
    {
        @ChildContent
    }
    </dialog>
</CascadingValue>
```

`Dialog.razor.cs`

```
public partial class Dialog : ComponentBase, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;
    private ElementReference dialogElement;
    private bool visible = false;

    public Dialog()
    {
        moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
            identifier: "import",
            args: "./scripts/dialogJsInterop.js")
        .AsTask());
    }

    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime jsRuntime { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> CapturedAttributes { get; set; }

    public async ValueTask ShowDialogAsync()
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("showDialog", dialogElement);
        visible = true;
    }

    public async ValueTask CloseDialogAsync()
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("closeDialog", dialogElement);
        visible = false;
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (moduleTask.IsValueCreated)
        {
            var module = await moduleTask.Value;
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

A this  stage you have a dialog that works.

I added the following components to make it more convenient.
Note: I do use bootstrap from here forward for styling, this could be changed easily to tailwind for example.

`DialogCloseButton.razor`

```
<button @attributes=CapturedAttributes @onclick=@CloseDialog />
```

`DialogCloseButton.razor.cs`

```
public partial class DialogCloseButton : ComponentBase
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Dialog Dialog { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> CapturedAttributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "class", "btn btn-close" }
    };

    private async Task CloseDialog() => await Dialog.CloseDialogAsync();
}
```

`DialogCloseButton.razor.css`

```
.btn:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

`DialogLayout.razor`

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between border-bottom border-1">
    <div class="flex-fill p-1 ps-3 fw-bolder user-select-none app-gradient text-white">
        @Header
    </div>
    <div class="p-1">
        <DialogCloseButton />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="p-3">
    @Content
</div>
```

`DialogLayout.razor.cs`

```
public partial class DialogLayout
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Header { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Content { get; set; }
}
```

`Usage :`

```
<Dialog @ref=@dialog class="p-0 border rounded shadow">
    <DialogLayout>
        <Header>
           <MessagesIcon Size=16 /> Add Message
        </Header>
        <Content>
            <MessageFormView />
        </Content>
    </DialogLayout>
</Dialog>
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" @onclick=@OpenDialog>Add Message</button>
@code {
    private Dialog dialog;

    ...

    private async Task OpenDialog() => await dialog.ShowDialogAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very minimal example of what you ask (I put everything in the `index.razor` file, but you can use CSS isolation and a dedicated `.cs` file for all the content inside the `@code{}` part.

```
@page "/index"
<style>
    .active {
        display: block;
    }
    .inactive {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<a class="btn btn-login" @onclick="RedirectPage" >Log in</a>

<div class="@PopupClass">
    Error: @ErrorText
</div>

@code{
    bool InvalidLogin {get; set;} = false;

    string PopupClass => InvalidLogin ? "active" : "inactive";
    public string ErrorText { get; set; } = "Example of exception";

    private void RedirectPage()
    {
        this.InvalidLogin = !this.InvalidLogin;
    }
}
```

Of course you will need to appropriate yourself this example in order to implement more concrete business logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is not necessary to create your own popup logic from scratch - many libraries with components available in NuGet Package Manager. Just open it and search 'blazor' - and you can find many already created components. As example -  *Syncfusion.Blazor.Popups*.