# Bootstrap Modal Popup using Blazor Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am working on blazor using asp.net core 6.0 I am facing issue to open bootstrap popup modal. When I click the modal button it doesn't show any modal popup. Also check for inspect elements there is no sign of modal html. I have added bootstrap css on layout. Reference Url is attached.

[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256798/how-to-use-bootstrap-modal-in-blazor-client-app/59257190#59257190)

Here is my implementation

Page

```html
<BlazorTaskItems.Pages.Modal @ref="modal"></BlazorTaskItems.Pages.Modal>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => modal.Open()">Modal!</button>
```

```cs
@code {

private BlazorTaskItems.Pages.Modal modal { get; set; }

}
```

Component

```html
<div class="modal @modalClass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:@modalDisplay; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">@Title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Body
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                @Footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@if (showBackdrop)
{
        <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
}
```

```cs
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? Body { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? Footer { get; set; }

    public Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();

    private string modalDisplay = "none;";
    private string modalClass = "";
    private bool showBackdrop = false;

    public void Open()
    {
        modalDisplay = "block;";
        modalClass = "show";
        showBackdrop = true;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        modalDisplay = "none";
        modalClass = "";
        showBackdrop = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muhammed - In additional to Jesse's answer here's a slightly different implementation you can use that implements async behaviour:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882886/is-it-possible-to-load-dynamically-existing-page-in-a-bootstrap-modal-body/71888010#71888010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `StateHasChanged();` (which happens to be in your linked code...)

```
public void Open()
{
    modalDisplay = "block;";
    modalClass = "show";
    showBackdrop = true;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Make sure to do this in the `Close()` method also.

Comment: better yet `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`, `StateHasChanged` is not thread safe and wrapping it serializes it so it doesn't run an exception.  See: https://blazor-university.com/components/multi-threaded-rendering/invokeasync/