Bootstrap modal backdrop not closing
I have a  bootstrap modal and when I click submit, the modal still doesn't close
I have an editform outside of the modal
<EditForm Model="newCategoryType" OnValidSubmit="HandleCreate">
  <DataAnnotationsValidator />
  <ValidationSummary />
  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="AddCategoryType" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Add category Type</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="CategoryTypeName">Category Type Name:</label>
                    <InputText id="CategoryTypeName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="newCategoryType.CategoryTypeName" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="CategoryTypeName">Category Type Description:</label>
                    <InputText id="CategoryTypeDescription" class="form-control" @bind-Value="newCategoryType.CategoryTypeDescription" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="CategoryType">Category Type Details:</label>
                    <InputText id="CategoryTypeDetails" class="form-control" @bind-Value="newCategoryType.CategoryTypeDetails" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="IsActive">IsActive:</label>
                    <InputCheckbox id="IsActive" class="form-control" @bind-Value="newCategoryType.IsActive" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</EditForm>

I wanted to have the modal close when I clicked submit
it closes when I click close, but when I click submit, the backdrop just stays gray, I can't interact with anything on the outside because its gray, Its a blazor Format, Its a bootstrap modal.

you can simply add attribute data-bs-dismiss="modal" to your submit button

There are many Blazor Modal Implementations  - Search "Blazor Modal Dialog" - [these even one of mine].   Also see many SO answers - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76114783/13065781 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76105876/13065781 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71888010/13065781

You have to register the closing,
doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/
you can add to your js:
$('#submit').modal('hide');


You have to manually close the modal after submitting

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
